# how to write to a file in python using a tkinter button?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, save

I am using tkinter and I want to write a string in a file whenever I press a button.
However, because I can change the string from a tkinter entry widget, in the file only the last string is written.
How can I write and save every string from tkinter in a file in different lines?

```
with open("Accountdata.txt", "r+") as f:
        
        f.write(str(usernames))
        f.write("\n")
        print(f.read())
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'a+') as f:  # append (plus) mode
    f.write(str(usernames) + '\n')
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```